# How to get the name of the variable the pointer is pointing to in LLVM

Tags: variables, pointers, llvm

I have a pointer to an array or to a variable. I want to get the name of that array or variable. How to get this in LLVM?

I am trying to instrument a function to which an array or variable is passed through pointer. I want to get the name of that array or variable argument. I am instrumenting my functions using LLVM.

Comment: I'm not an LLVM expert, but without more information, this doesn't seem answerable.  Perhaps you could explain a little bit more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: What  does this have to do with LLVM? Are you talking about register renaming?

Comment: I am trying to instrument a function to which an array or variable is passed through pointer. I want to get the name of that array or variable argument. I am instrumenting my functions using LLVM.

Comment: That's a *little* better, but maybe you can put a little more effort into your question?  Have a look at some of the questions other people have asked that were well-received here.  Most of the time, you will see them explain what they're trying to do, what they have tried, why it didn't work, etc.  They might even show some code they have written.  Edit your question, rather than trying to put further explanation into the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use debug information for that, because otherwise names from the original C code do not get represented in LLVM IR, in the general case. See the [debug info document](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html). In particular, look in the sections about "`@llvm.dbg.declare`" and "Global Value Descriptors"